# Derive the general formula for the Taylor series of $\frac{1}{1-x}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, solution-verification, power-series, taylor-expansion

> The Maclaurin series for $\frac{1}{1-x}$ is simply the geometric series. However, this series converges if and only if $\lvert x \rvert < 1$, despite the fact that $f(x)$ is defined for all $x\neq 1$. In this problem, you will explore other representations of $f(x)$ by Taylor series.
>
> (a) Give a general formula for the Taylor series of $f(x) = \frac{1}{1-x} $ at $a \neq 1$

For (a), I create this formula by degree-$n$ Taylor polynomials and the remainder. But I'm not sure whether it's a general formula.

> (b) For what values of $x$ does this Taylor series converge? Express your answer as an interval, in terms of $a$.

For (b), I tried to prove the remainder $\to 0$,  as $n\to\infty$. My formula for the remainder is

$$ (n+1)! \int_{a}^{x} \frac{(x-t)^n}{(1-t)^{n+2}} \, \mathrm{d}t.$$

But I don't know how to show the value of $x$ when this remainder is approaching 0 as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: By writing $$f(x) = \frac{1}{1-a-(x-a)} = \frac{1}{1-a}\cdot\frac{1}{1-\frac{x-a}{1-a}},$$ you can not only use the geometric series to identify the Taylor series for $f(x)$ about $x=a$ but also determine the interval of convergence.

Answer (score 2):

Since

$$ f^{(n)}(x)=\frac{n!}{(1-x)^{n+1}}, $$

the Taylor series for $f(x)$ about $x=a$ (with $a\neq1$) is given by

$$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!}(x-a)^n = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(x-a)^n}{(1-a)^{n+1}}. $$

This is nothing but a geometric series with the common ratio $r=\frac{x-a}{1-a}$, and so, it converges precisely when $\left| r \right| < 1$. So the interval of convergence is

$$ (a-\left|1-a\right|, a+\left|1-a\right|). $$